# Preg Match Issue with HTML Chars

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-match

I am really not sure why this is not working, as I understoond it `(.*?)` should match all characters. I have a feeling it may have something to do with special characters in the HMTL?

Here is my code

```
preg_match( '/butt_box(.*?)img/',$return_string, $returned_val);
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to extract (attempting to extract what is between butt_box and the first img tag following that.

```
<table class="butt_box">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td style="width:100%;">
            <div class="product_box3_price" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; text-align:center;"><strong>Price Unavailable</strong><br>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div style="padding: 9px 0 6px 0"><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com.au/index.php?main_page=product_info&amp;products_id=1399"><img src="includes/templates/theme243/buttons/english/button_goto_prod_details.gif" alt="Go To This Product's Detailed Information" title=" Go To This Product's Detailed Information " width="144" height="36"></a><br>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're parsing html with regex. That's not good.

Comment: Why not? What's the alternative?

Comment: I don't want to get into it but a quick google search should straighten you out.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Cool thanks for the link, ill have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `s` PCRE modifier to allow the dot to match newlines.

```
preg_match( '/butt_box(.*?)img/s',$return_string, $returned_val);
```